# SQL запрос дополнительно выбрать 20 товаров с нулевыми остатками

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `products` и есть запрос `select * from products where quantity > 0` . Нужно дополнительно еще выбрать 20 записей где  `quantity = 0` . Можно это как-то сделать не используя union?

Answer (score 2):

Так и укажите в условии выборки, то что надо ещё 20 записей:

```
select id, qty
from  (
    select id, qty, row_number() over(order by null) rnum 
    from products) 
where qty > 0 or (rnum <=20 and qty = 0);

        ID        QTY
---------- ----------
         1          0
         2          0
         3          0
[...]
        19          0
        20          0
        31         10
        32         10
[...]
```

**Важно:** в вопросе не указано условие сортировки, поэтому запрос выше вернёт *случайный* набор записей.

Comment: Версия mysql  5.7.29. не поддерживает row_number. Перейти на версию>8 нет возможности

Comment: А причём здесь версия mysql 5.7.29? Вы задали вопрос по стандартному SQL.

Comment: Вот [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ee2a133b17a04b835fc8dd46ab403696) для MySQL 5.7.